# Why is async filter slower than regular filter in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, filter, filtering, kotlin-coroutines

If I have a huge collection that I want to filter the first thing I would try is this:

```kotlin
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    var i = 0
    val hugeCollection = buildList {
        repeat(5_000_000) {
            add(i++)
        }
    }
    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")
    var filteredList: List<Int> = listOf()

    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        filteredList = hugeCollection.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
    }

    println("Elapsed time: $elapsedTime ms")
    println("Size of filteredList: ${filteredList.size}")
}
```

For that I get this output:

> Size of hugeCollection: 5000000

> Elapsed time: 21 ms

> Size of filteredList: 2500000

Then I thought why not run the comparison for all elements simultaneously:

```kotlin
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    var i = 0
    val hugeCollection = buildList {
        repeat(5_000_000) {
            add(i++)
        }
    }
    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")
    var filteredList: List<Int> = listOf()

    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        filteredList = hugeCollection
            .map { number ->
                async(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { Pair(number, number % 2 == 0) }
            }.map { deferredPair -> deferredPair.await() }
            .filter { pair -> pair.second }
            .map { pair -> pair.first }
    }

    println("Elapsed time: $elapsedTime ms")
    println("Size of filteredList: ${filteredList.size}")
}
```

But then I get this output:

> Size of hugeCollection: 5000000

> Elapsed time: 791 ms

> Size of filteredList: 2500000

I tried a couple different Dispatcher configurations (Dispatcher.Unconfinded, Dispatchers.Default, Dispatchers.IO and Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(5_000_000)) and Unconfined was the fastest in this case

Can someone explain why the second variant is slower?

Comment: Because the second variant needs to do a lot more work: Splitting it up, creating coroutines, combining the results back together, et cetera. And the filter calculation itself isn't particularly expensive, so there's not much to gain.

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced that awaiting each `Job` individually is a good idea. Better to collect them in a list and use `awaitAll`. Although I can't be sure if that has a significant effect on performance here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Jorn is right. My filter function was not expensive enough.

With these new versions, the asynchronous one is faster. (Notice the changes repeat(5_000) and delay(1))

Regular:

```kotlin
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    var i = 0
    val hugeCollection = buildList {
        repeat(5_000) { //change 1
            add(i++)
        }
    }
    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")
    var filteredList: List<Int> = listOf()

    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        filteredList = hugeCollection.filter {
            delay(1) //change 2
            it % 2 == 0
        }
    }

    println("Elapsed time: $elapsedTime ms")
    println("Size of filteredList: ${filteredList.size}")
}
```

> Size of hugeCollection: 5000

> Elapsed time: 6760 ms

> Size of filteredList: 2500

Async:

```kotlin
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    var i = 0
    val hugeCollection = buildList {
        repeat(5_000) { //change 1
            add(i++)
        }
    }
    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")
    var filteredList: List<Int> = listOf()
    
    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        filteredList = hugeCollection
            .map { number ->
                async(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
                    delay(1) //change 2
                    Pair(number, number % 2 == 0)
                }
            }.map { deferredPair -> deferredPair.await() }
            .filter { pair -> pair.second }
            .map { pair -> pair.first }
    }
    
    println("Elapsed time: $elapsedTime ms")
    println("Size of filteredList: ${filteredList.size}")
}
```

> Size of hugeCollection: 5000

> Elapsed time: 57 ms

> Size of filteredList: 2500

Comment: This isn't a valid benchmark anyway. You need to use a benchmarking library to be able to draw any conclusions.

Comment: To mock "heavy work" you want to use `Thread.sleep()`, with `delay` you just reschedule your continuations without actually occupying available threads. You will also want to use Dispatchers.default because unconfined one will just hang without suspending points.