# What is the best way to filter big lists in kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, filter, kotlin-coroutines

If I have a big list with a lot of entries what is the best way to filter it?

I came up with this to asynchronously filter a big list:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    var i = 0
    val hugeCollection = buildList {
        repeat(5_000_000) {
            add(i++)
        }
    }

    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")

    val filteredList = hugeCollection
        .map { number ->
            async {
                Pair(number, number % 2 == 0)
            }
        }.map { deferred -> deferred.await() }
        .filter { pair -> pair.second }
        .map { pair -> pair.first }

    println("Size of filteredList: ${filteredList.size}")
}
```

Is there a better way? What if the filter is a very expensive calculation?

Comment: I'll restate my comment from [the previous time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366810/8681): Making this async requires splitting it up, creating coroutines, combining the results back together, et cetera. And the filter calculation itself isn't particularly expensive, so there's not much to gain.

Comment: `map { deferred -> deferred.await() }` can be replaced with the superior `awaitAll()`. Look at the documentation to see why it’s better aside from being concise. But like Jorn says, a lot of the coroutines machinery and the setup you’re doing has to be done on the thread you’re calling from, and in this case is more work than the tiny bit of work you’re doing asynchronously.

Comment: If `number % 2 == 0` was instead some very long, CPU intensive task, maybe this would make sense. Otherwise, if the issue is just that it’s a very long list, you could just do the filter operation on the Default dispatcher, but don’t try to split it up and parallelize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is a perfect match for Java's native parallel streams. I strongly suggest you look into using them. Here's some benchmark code you can try out to see the difference (notice I'm using a bit more heavyweight filter function):

```
suspend fun main() {
    val hugeCollection = (1..10_000_000).toList()
    println("Size of hugeCollection: ${hugeCollection.size}")

    for (a in 1..3) {
        var resultSize = 0
        measureTimeMillis {
            resultSize = computeWithAsync(hugeCollection).size
        }.also {
            println("Took $it millis")
        }
        println("Size of filteredList: $resultSize")
    }
}

suspend fun computeWithAsync(hugeCollection: List<Int>) = coroutineScope {
    withContext(Default) {
        hugeCollection
                .map { number ->
                    async {
                        Pair(number, number.toDouble().pow(1.83).toLong() % 2 == 0L)
                    }
                }.map { deferred -> deferred.await() }
                .filter { pair -> pair.second }
                .map { pair -> pair.first }
    }
}

fun computeWithParallelStream(hugeCollection: List<Int>) =
        hugeCollection.parallelStream()
                .map { number -> Pair(number, number.toDouble().pow(1.83).toLong() % 2 == 0L) }
                .filter { pair -> pair.second }
                .map { pair -> pair.first }
                .collect(toList())
```

Example of output with `computeWithAsync`:

```
Size of hugeCollection: 5000000
Took 2958 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
Took 2724 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
Took 2523 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
```

Example of output with `computeWithParallelStream`:

```
Size of hugeCollection: 5000000
Took 177 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
Took 112 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
Took 107 millis
Size of filteredList: 2498864
```

Whereas `async` creates a new task for each individual element, a parallel Java stream always creates the same optimal number of tasks -- as many as you have CPU cores. The overhead of switching from task to task is the main explainer for the difference in the performance we see.

Once the filtering function is heavy enough (~ 1 ms per element or more), we can expect this overhead to become less relevant. Still, I'd argue that the Java parallel stream is still the go-to tool for parallel computation on large lists.